# Angular 2 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to use angular 2 with Visual Studio 2013 (ASP.NET MVC project)
I was looking for tutorials but only found Visual Studio 2015 ones.

Comment: You can do angular with a notepad.exe. It will not be the best experience, but it is possible. If you are looking on tutorials, just follow them for VS2015 and apply the same steps in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using a newer version of Visual Studio. The Community edition of [VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) is "free" for students, open-source contributors, and individuals.

This is a 2(soon 3) part blog that covers what you want to achieve. It also covers usage of [VS Code](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

[How to create an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Angular 6 in Visual Studio Part 1](https://medium.com/asp-net-and-angular/how-to-create-an-asp-net-mvc-5-project-with-angular-6-in-visual-studio-part-1-8b116e19a335)

[How to create an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Angular 6 in Visual Studio Part 2](https://medium.com/asp-net-and-angular/how-to-create-an-asp-net-mvc-5-project-with-angular-6-in-visual-studio-part-2-1cea70c85114)

Should be possible to follow the guide using VS2013/15 also. Could be some differences.

Comment: it's also with 2015 right ?. Any possibility to work with 2013 ?